# If statement inside a for loop (MS Batch)

Tags: loops, batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, echo

I'm having some troubles with the following script I made:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set type=str
set idx=0
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (equipment.ini)  do (
    if !type! == str (
        set /a idx=!idx!+1
        set /a es.!idx!=%%a
        echo !es.!idx!!
        set type=int
    ) else (
        set /a ei.!idx!=%%a
        echo !ei.!idx!!
        set type=str
    )
)
```

The script is supposed to read from the file equipment.ini and save the values in 2 different variables which switch every time the for loop is repeated.
%es.1% would contain the name of a weapon while %ei.1% would contain it's ID and so forth.

The for and if loops seem to work like they should, but echo'ing the value does not.
Been pulling my hair out of frustration since yesterday night as I know the solution is probably very simple but I just can't see it atm.

If anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please give a exemple of your `equipment.ini`.

Comment: Test
1001
Test2
1002
Test3
1003 They are of course new lines every time, but I can't put that in the comment section.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set type=str
set idx=0
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (equipment.ini)  do (
    if !type! == str (
        set /a idx=!idx!+1
        set /a es.!idx!=%%a
        for %%# in (!idx!) do echo !es.%%#!
        set type=int
    ) else (
        set /a ei.!idx!=%%a
        for %%# in (!idx!) do echo !es.%%#!
        set type=str
    )
)
```

Comment: This works, but for some reason only works on ei, for es the value stays 0 for some reason, even after fixing the tiny mistake in your example (2x es)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
   call echo %%ei.!idx!%%
```

and its mate...

Comment: This works, but for some reason only works on ei, for es the value stays 0 for some reason.

Comment: Your data `test*` is not numeric, hence `set /a es.!idx!=%%a` will set the variable to 0. Lose the `/a`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@echo off&cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set $count=1
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in ('type equipment.ini') do (set es!$count!=%%a
                                                               set ei!$count!=%%b
                                                               set /a $count+=1)

set e
```

That wil work if your equipment.ini have this format :

```
test 1000
test1 1001
test2 1002
test3 1003
```